# joomla 2.5.6 menu related

Tags: joomla

On my website : www.openlx.com, in the submenu (below the main menu - "Home"), the URL currently looks like: http://openlx.com/home/aboutus.html

Same way, in all the sub-menus to the main-manu "Home", the word "home" is part of the URL.
I want to remove this word "home" from the URL, and same for all the sub-menus to all the menus.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new menu and call it "Shortcuts" or something similar that makes sense to you.
2. Don't create a menu module for it and don't display it anywhere.
3. Move your menu items from beneath the "Home" menu item to the top level of "Shortcuts" menu. As they are top level items in the "Shortcuts" menu they won't have the `/home/` before them.
4. Under your "Home" menu item recreated each of the menu items as a "[Menu Item Alias](http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help16%3aMenus_Menu_Item_Manager_Edit#Menu_Item_Alias)" (found under the "System Links" Heading in when choosing the menu item type). The alias will now use the path of the menu item in the "Shortcuts" menu and you not see the `/home/` anymore.